# Binding to Routed Command in Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a WPF project using the MVVM pattern.  I need to add a trigger to send a routed command to the view model for every textbox on all of my edit screens.

I would like to do this by using a style in by resource dictionary that I apply to all of my textboxes.  To make life easy, I would like to do the command binding in the resource dictionary.  Something like the following -

```
<Style x:Key="EditTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.IsFocused">
            <Actions:InvokeCommand Command="{Binding UpdateHelpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Where Actions:InvokeCommand is a From the [JulMar MVVM Helpers + Behaviors](http://mvvmhelpers.codeplex.com/) library.  This function calls a routed command in view model.

Any suggestions as to how this can be done without manually adding it to each control?

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What is stopping you from using a typed Style (Style without a key defined) instead of the named Style that you are currently using?  That would do away with the need to specify the Style for each textbox.

Comment: That could be done.  However, because of the way my overall theme is put together, just redefining type "global" textbox style will has a number of unfortunate side effects for me.  The textbox control is used as part of the the control template for other controls.

Comment: Why not do this in code then?  You can traverse the logical tree in code and anything that you find which is a TextBox you can add the event handler to.

Comment: That is my fall-back option. It just seems to be an un-elegant solution.

Comment: It is probably the best you are going to be able to do.  Theoretically you could have TextBoxes with different styles throughout your application which all are bound to the same command.  The bound command isn't based on the look or Style of the TextBoxes but is based on the fact that their Type is TextBox.  So setting a global property like this in a Style doesn't seem like the natural way to accomplish this task.  It seems more natural and straightforward to solve this problem by basing the command binding on the Type of the control rather than on the Style.